# Set up a Screencast video in Drupal website

Tags: iphone, drupal, mp4, vimeo

I've set up a Drupal website and would like to have video box that pops up when a user clicks a picture graphic. Sounds simple enough, but it turns out it is not straightforward in the land of Drupal, flash, codecs, and iphone...
Here's what I'd like:

1. User clicks a link on my Drupal website, a video box player pops up as a mini-box player for the user to watch in a PC or Mac.
2. For iphone users, want the ability for them to view video on iPhone (which means it can't be flash).

Here's where I am so far. I recorded a screencast using both Camtasia for Mac and Screenflow. But I don't know which format to encode the video- or how to.

I've read that JW player (long tail video) is a good player because it will play both flash and HTML (good for iPhone), but then also read that Drupal and JWplayer does do a popup video window from a link. Is that true?

So before embarking further, I'd love some input on how to proceed? Which encoding format, how to achieve pop-up video player, and have ability to play on iPhone. Of course all through a Drupal site. Btw- I would be hosting the video on Vimeo, or Amazon's cloudfront.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be more appropriate for the new Drupal Stack Exchange site: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the vimeo iframe code for embedding the video, you get [iPhone playability](http://vimeo.com/blog:334) for free.